# After rebooting different login UI appeared and after logged in Ubuntu desktop doesn't load correctly only wallpaper available

Tags: 16.04, unity, login, desktop-environments

After restarting Ubuntu this `tty`-like login screen appeared and once logged in Ubuntu desktop is not working properly. Only wallpaper is visible (no launcher and pane).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

[image: different login UI]

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. question you referenced asked 5 year ago and it doesn't has any issue like appearing different login screen. And also i tried solution you referenced before posting this and it didn't work.

Comment: That question is what we call a *canonical post*. It may be old, but, in theory, it is maintained and updated and has many solutions to different variations on this problem. When you ask a question, please do add details of what you  have already tried, otherwise, people will most likely suggest those things.